# Is it true that a JSON document will not be parseable until the last byte is written?

Tags: json

Is the following hypothesis valid?

> Leaving aside whitespace, once the first character of a JSON document
>   has been written,  the resulting stream will not parse as valid JSON
>   until the last character has been written.

I'm interested in using this assumption so that when I have one process writing a file and another reading it, I can safely ignore partially-written files by ignoring anything that doesn't parse as valid JSON.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but maybe a simple flag (for example, a changing file extension) would work better? Seems like overkill to read and attempt to parse the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it depends on the parser you are using... it seems than any scrupulous parser would follow that rule due to the structure of JSON... curly brackets around every "object" key/value pair, including any wrapping document `{ }`).

As always with programming, test rather than assume.